# I have a contrast enhancement function for pixel intensities between 0-1. How can I reverse this

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the function to enhance contrast for pixel intensities between $0-1$

$f(x) = \cfrac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\text{gain}(\text{cutoff}-x)}}$

I have a whole bunch of images that I need to reverse back to original, How should I to this

Comment: Do you know how to solve for the inverse of a function?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the function,

$$y=\frac{1}{1+e^{a(c-x)}}$$
$$e^{a(c-x)}=1/y-1$$
$$a(c-x)=\ln (1/y-1)$$
$$x=c-\frac1a\ln(1/y-1)$$
However if some quantization or clipping was going on, you won't be able to reverse the transformation completely.